# How to return a JSON with an array in object using PHP json_encode()

Tags: json

I'm trying to return JSON values like below using PHP:

{"a":"valuea","b":"valueb","c":[{"c1":"valuec1","c2":"valuec2"}]}

following are the PHP code

```
<?php 
     $data = array(
    'a' => 'valuea',
    'b' => 'valueb',
    'c' => array(
        'c1' => 'valuec1',
        'c2' => 'valuec2',
        ),
    );
echo json_encode($data);
```

Then I got this:
{"a":"valuea","b":"valueb","c":{"c1":"valuec1","c2":"valuec2"}}

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be ugly but here it is.

```
<?php 
     $data = array(
    'a' => 'valuea',
    'b' => 'valueb',
    'c' => array(
             array(
               'c1' => 'valuec1',
               'c2' => 'valuec2')
           ),
    );
echo json_encode($data);
```

tested it using the http://phpfiddle.org/;

The idea is the first array you create for c will not be considered as a collection because that is an OBJECT. Making a nested array inside the first array for c will make the c as a collection.